# Using formal methods when you test applications

Tags: terminology

Does anybody always follow concepts like, Cyclomatic Complexity, Equivalence Partitioning,
Boundary Value Analysis in their testing applications ? or Let me know the best way to cover these techniques when testing application.

Comment: I gave an answer to this, however, I think this question can be reworded.  As it stands right now, it seems to be aimed at gathering a lot of opinions and anecdotal experience rather than practical knowledge.

Comment: Please go ahead and make necessary changes to add value to the question. Thanks for answering too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test heuristics sheet is another useful document which provides checklist based on concepts and real-world experience. It took time to figureout the hyperlink to post it for this question. Please check http://testobsessed.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/testheuristicscheatsheetv1.pdf. I found this checklist useful for my reference.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I wouldn't say I formally say "Hey, I'm doing Boundary Value Analysis".  However, these are techniques that I've learned over the years that I apply in my evaluations almost intuitively.  Yeah, there's probably room for me to more formalize this, but it's more a matter of practical application than formalization.

Answer (score 4):

Cyclomatic complexity is one way to assess or measure the complexity of a chunck of code (specifically the number of linearly indpendent paths). Some developers may use this measure to refactor complex code, or testers may use this to identify areas of the code that may be a "target rich environment" that is more likely to have issues.

Equivalence partitioning, boundary value analysis, etc. are functional testing techniques and as Tristaan indicates all testers often informally apply the concepts of these techniques during their testing.

Comment: Well put, Bj.  I can believe that measuring cyclomatic complexity might help identify target-rich environments, but that kind of analysis is usually beyond my time budget.  Equivalence partitioning and boundary value analysis are part and parcel of the job.

Answer (score 3):

I apply such concepts when and if they are appropriate for the situation at hand.

I can say with certainty that I don't **always** follow such concepts.